# cant pass variable into df.query()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, streamlit

I am having an error for this query selection.

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st
import plotly.express as px

st.set_page_config(page_title="Asset List", page_icon=":bar_chart:", layout="wide")
st.header('Asset List 2023')
st.subheader("Network Operations")

excel_file = 'file.xlsx'
sheet_name = 'Asset List'

# --- Main Data ---

df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, 
                   sheet_name=sheet_name,
                   usecols='C,E,F,H,I,J,K,L,Q:S',
                   header=0)

df = df.astype(str)

# --- Load the dataframe ---

st.dataframe(df)

# --- SIDEBAR ---

st.sidebar.header("Please Filter Here")

site_codes_select = st.sidebar.selectbox("Select the SITE:", options=df['Site Code'].unique().tolist())
under_maint = st.sidebar.radio("Under Mainteance?",["Yes", "No"])
Maint_Required = st.sidebar.radio("Mainteance Required?", ["Yes", "No"])

df_selection = df.query('Site Code == site_codes_select')

st.dataframe(df_selection)
```

if I remove df_selection, it doesnt give me any error.
and this is the fricking error that I am getting:

**SyntaxError: File "", line 1 Site Code ==site_codes_select ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax**

can you please help me?

Comment: You likely need `df.query('\`Site Code\` == @site_codes_select')`